# How to include factory method into abstract class?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to include factory method into abstract class? I've got a lot of model classes which I use to populate data. They all have same methods in them `fromMap` and `toMap` where fromMap is an factory method

```
class MyModelClass implements Tools {
//toMap

 Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
     ...
    };
  }

//fromMap

factory MyModelClass.fromMap(
      Map<String, dynamic> data) {
...
return MyModelClass(...)}
}
```

I can easily include `toMap` method but trouble with factory one

```
abstract class Tools {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
  ///here the factory method
}
```

Reason to put these methods in to abstract class is to be able to use the abstract class only in my database class to retrieve and send data.

**An idea what comes to my mind**

```
abstract class Tools {
      Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
      factory Tools.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data, String sw) {
    if (sw == 'a')
      return MyModelClass1();
    else
      return MyModelClass2();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why is the class abstract if it has a factory?

Comment: @RémiRousselet it doesn't have factory method yet... I wish to add the factory method into the abstract class. Not sure if that is possible

Comment: @RémiRousselet I've edited the code so it is more clear what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Your factory constructor must return an instance of `MyModelClass`, but that's abstract and cannot be instantiated.  It *can* instantiate and return a (possibly private) concrete, derived class.  That is what `Map`'s constructor does. (`Map` is an abstract class with factory constructors.)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I'm using my model classes to retrieve and send data. I do not initialise the class, I only need to get to those 2 methods from that abstract class. I know that the factory must return any model class in my case so is it somehow possible to make it working even with perhaps added switch parameter which would change a model class based on some parameter?

Comment: Please take a look at updated code at the bottom of my question to see what I meant